# ¿Cómo tomar subcadenas de una cadena separados por un carácter en Java?

Tags: java, string

Quiero obtener los nombres en la cadena: `"Pedro#Juan#Manuel#Antonio"`

Por separado:

- Pedro
- Juan
- Manuel
- Antonio

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida. Estás haciendo algunas preguntas muy básicas que salen en la primera googleada, trata de evitarlas realizando investigación previa

Comment: tomar trosos? de que exactamente?

Answer (score 2):

Debes utilizar la función split() , que separa una cadena de acuerdo a un caracter específico, en éste caso "#".

```
String cadena = "Pedro#Juan#Manuel#Antonio";

String[] trozos = cadena.split("#");

String nombre1 = trozos[0]; // Pedro

String nombre2 = trozos[1]; // Juan

String nombre3 = trozos[2]; // Manuel

String nombre4 = trozos[3]; // Antonio
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Puede que te sirva esto

```
public class Delimitadores {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String sTiempo = "avila#12#24#soleado";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sTiempo,"#");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens())
    System.out.println (st.nextToken());
    }

}
```

Comment: si lo que buscas es separa palabras por algun delimitador dimelo y te respondo con lo que necesitas.